# What's better to use in Angular - src or [src]

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Just want to ask what is recommended to use with Angular, standard html `src` or Angular `[src]`? And why?

**Edit**: I have following code in my html component:

```
<img class="logo" src="../app/media/appLogo.png">
```

It is fine? If not, how should I change it to work together with `[src]`?

**Edit2**: Is there any other, better way to do it, instead of plain html `src`? Or this is the best solution actually?

Comment: I updated my answer to your edits.

Answer (score 9):

`[...]="..."` is for object binding `...="{{...}}"` is for binding with string interpolation. If you want to bind a string it doesn't matter what you use. If you want to bind an object or array value you need to use `[...]="...". Besides that it's entirely up to you.

```
<img class="logo" src="../app/media/appLogo.png">
```

Is not related to Angular2 at all, thats just plain HTML (no `[]` and no `{{}}`). If you add `[]` around `src`, then Angular will treat `../app/media/appLogo.png` as an expression, which it clearly isn't.

When DomSanitizer is used `[src]="..."` is mandatory because the value no longer is a string, but an object and using `{{}}` would stringify it in an invalid way.

Comment: but in most of the cases we use `[]` while binding to `img` tag why so ?

Comment: I guess because `[]` always works (all components and properties) and `{{}}` only works for strings. I prefer `[]` because it stands out more and makes it more obvious that binding is used here, `{{}}` can be somewhere within the value if prefix and suffix are static, which makes it IMHO easy to miss.

Comment: If there is no expression to evaluate, then yes. In this case `[]` or `{{}}` would just cause an error message.

Comment: "better" is a bit vague. Better in what regard? If you use `appLogo.png` in many places, you could move `../app/media/appLogo.png` to a global constant and use this constant everywhere where you want to show the application logo for better maintainability, but if you display this image in many places IMHO a better approach would be an `AppLogo` component.

Comment: Is angular 2 fit for large scale application like ERP application?

Answer (score 5):

Using regular `src` sets the Attribute where setting `[src]` sets the property. Considering that for an image (I assume you're talking about an image but you don't say) the `src` attribute is used to set the corresponding property they will both work.

There is one big reason to use `[src]` though. Browsers tend to start downloading whatever you put in the `src` attribute while parsing the html. So lets say you do this:

```
<img src="{{myImgSrc}}"/>
```

The browsers will often immediately start downloading `{{myImgSrc}}`, which will lead to a 404 in the console. Using the following is therefor slightly better:

```
<img [src]="myImgSrc"/>
```

Comment: "src sets the Attribute where setting [src]" is not enirely true. `src="{{myImgSrc}}"` sets the property the same as `[src]="myImgSrc"` does. `src="/assets/someimg.png"` sets the attribute instead of the property because no binding is involved at all. `[attr.src]="myImgSrc"` or `attr.src="{{myImgSrc}}"` bind to the attribute instead of to the property.

Answer (score 1):

If you have static anchor link, then go ahead with

```
<img class="logo" src="../app/media/appLogo.png">
```

When binding from the component, then either of the below will work.

```
<img class="logo" [src]="image_src">
<img class="logo" src="{{ image_src }}">
```

In component.ts

```
image_src: string = '../app/media/appLogo.png';
```