# Way to make electron be aware of the assets without changing the base href in angular

Tags: angular, electron

I need to build my angular v12 app with electron.

Everything work as expected, but the app isn't capable of reading the assets.

I have [read](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45269374/11135174) that I should change the base ref, into the `index.html` to be like this `<base href="./">`

But doing so makes my app not working properly with the guards I did implement. *It does change the location and add `/en/` if you are english, `/de/` if you're germane, ...*

So I'm trying to find another solution to loads the assets without having to change the base ref.

Does somebody have any idea?

Comment: Any [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to start with ?

Comment: It's a bit hard to provide a minimal reproducible example, and I think, every developer that worked with angular & Electron should have faced the same error. That said, I will upload one as soon as I have the time for it.