# Angular 4 :Unable to open 'image.png': no provider for the image

Tags: angular

I have recently started learning angular 4 and came up with a very basic issue.
I tried giving path of an image in the img tag but got the following error

*Unable to open 'image.png': no provider for* **c:/Surbhi/MyPractice/image.png**. Code snippet is given below.

```
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>
    Welcome to {{ title }}!
  </h1>
  <img width="300" alt="Angular Logo" src="C:\Surbhi\MyPractice\image.png">
</div>
<h2>ABC </h2>
<ul>
  <li>
    <h2><a target="_blank" rel="noopener" href="https://angular.io/tutorial">Tour of Heroes</a></h2>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h2><a target="_blank" rel="noopener" href="https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki">CLI Documentation</a></h2>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h2><a target="_blank" rel="noopener" href="https://blog.angular.io/">Angular blog</a></h2>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: you wont be able to render img by providing absolute path. Place it in the asset folder and then provide relative path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your image in assets folder and give path something like this

```
<img width="300" alt="Angular Logo" src="/assets/images/image.png">
```

Comment: Is there any other way we can give absolue path, or the only  approach possible is through assets folder only

Answer (score 0):

It is a convention to put the images we use in the project in the assets folder of the respective project. And please research the problems a little more.
[maybe refer to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42793292/how-to-load-image-and-other-assets-in-angular-2-project?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)