# How to call angular method in html?

Tags: angular6

I'm using 
***ngFor(*ngFor="let radio of items)** in div element and inside of this div , using an **img** element.I am trying to set the src like  **[src]="radio.getIsActiveIcon()**" but 
"46 ERROR TypeError: _v.context.$implicit.getIsActiveIcon is not a function at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] " error happens.
My img element and getIsActiveIcon func is;

```
<img class="is-active-image" [src]="radio.getIsActiveIcon()">

public getIsActiveIcon(): string {
    if (this.isActive === 1) {
        return 'assets/img/ic_active.png';
    }
    return 'assets/img/ic_not_active.png';
}
```

Comment: Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42793292/how-to-load-image-and-other-assets-in-angular-2-project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally,I used Pipe and it works.it's more clear.

Answer (score 0):

```
<img class="is-active-image" [src]="getIsActiveIcon()">
```

Not sure what does radio means, but all you have to do is call the function.

Comment: I need to access gecIsActiveIcon() from Radio.ts because it depends on the isActive value inside of Radio.

Answer (score 0):

**Preventing cross-site scripting (XSS)** 
Cross-site scripting (XSS) enables attackers to inject malicious code into web pages. Such code can then, for example, steal user data (in particular, login data) or perform actions to impersonate the user. This is one of the most common attacks on the web.

To block XSS attacks, you must prevent malicious code from entering the DOM (Document Object Model). For example, if attackers can trick you into inserting a  tag in the DOM, they can run arbitrary code on your website. The attack isn't limited to  tags—many elements and properties in the DOM allow code execution, for example,  and . If attacker-controlled data enters the DOM, expect security vulnerabilities.

for more info go here [Angular Security](https://angular.io/guide/security#xss)

Comment: This works                                                                                                                                          <img class="is-active-image"
                                 [src]="radio.isActive == 1 ? 'assets/img/ic_active.png' : 'assets/img/ic_not_active.png'">

Comment: Using function to return image url in img tag was a bad idea