# Angular Image cannot be loaded

Tags: html, angular, angular6

On the template **list of users**, I have a column to show the **identity image** (stored on database) of each user.

On the **template file**, I have:

```
    <td> 
       <img src="{{emptyStr.concat(user.pathImage.substr(user.pathImage.indexOf('/assets')))}}" style="max-width:30px"/>
       <br/>
       {{user.nameImage}}
       <br/>
       {{emptyStr.concat(user.pathImage.substr(user.pathImage.indexOf('/assets')))}}
    </td>
```

On the **component file**,  `emptyStr = "..";`

As displayed bellow:

[image]

The name and the url of the image are displayed correctly.
However, the image cannot be loaded.

On firefox, there's no error.

However on chrome, I got this error:
[image]

Also, I got:
[image]

That means that this image doesn't exists on file **upload**, but no, that exists as displayed by this screenshot.
[image]

I think there's a problem of synchronization, because after made some changes on sublime tool, the console `ng server` will update and both **2 images are shown**.

Have you please any idea about solving that issue ?.
Big thanks.

Comment: compile app with this option `ng build --prod --output-hashing none`, this might help

Comment: In chrome developer tools, when you run the image url in a different window, does the image come up?

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with angular. Your trying to load an image that doesn't exist.

Comment: Hello Sir @R.Richards, thanks for your reply. On firefox, there isn't any error, but on chrome, I attached the error to my question.Could you please take a look ?.

Comment: Hello Sir @Liam, Big thanks for your reply. no Sir the two images are exist. I attached the folder **upload** that approves the existence of the both images.I think there's a problem of synchronization, because after made some changes on sublime tool, the console ng server will update and the 2 images are shown. Have you please any idea?. Big thanks.

Comment: Have a look at [How to load image (and other assets) in Angular an project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42793292/how-to-load-image-and-other-assets-in-angular-2-project)

Comment: Hello Sir @Liam, thanks for your reply. But none of those cases corresponds with mine. My problem is that the uploaded image already exists. but cannot be loaded synchronously. It be loaded after run **ng serve**. Have you please any explication ?. Big thanks.

Comment: Hello Sir @AkberIqbal, thanks for your reply. I made some changes on my question, could you please take a look?. Big thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this way:

On the **template .html**:

```
< img src="{{showImage(user.id)}}" alt="{{showImage(user.id)}}" style="max-width:30px"/>
```

On the **component .ts**:

```
strIntoObjExp: String[] = [];
specialUser: User;
user: User;

showImage(id: number) : String
{
    var requesta = new XMLHttpRequest();
    requesta.open('GET', 'http://localhost:6227/api/auth/getallfiles', false);
    requesta.send(null);

    this.strIntoObjExp = JSON.parse(requesta.responseText);

    var requestb = new XMLHttpRequest();
    requestb.open('GET', 'http://localhost:6227/api/auth/users/' + id, false);
    requestb.send(null);

    this.specialUser = JSON.parse(requestb.responseText);

    this.strIntoObjExp.forEach((exp: String) =>
    {
         if(exp.includes(this.specialUser.nameImage.substring(0, this.specialUser.nameImage.lastIndexOf("."))))
         {
              this.imagePath = exp;
         }
    });
    return this.imagePath;
}
```

HTH