# How to import a sound file into react typescript component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, audio, import

I have a small mp3 file located in project_root/src/audio/alarm.mp3.

I try to import like so:

```
  import alarm from "./audio/alarm.mp3";
```

But when I try to import it into App.tsx, I get this compiler error:

```
  Cannot find module './audio/alarm.mp3'.
```

But I can import images just fine.

Answer (score 22):

Place the audio in the assets and write a custom typing file called audio.d.ts with the following code :-

```
declare module '*.mp3';
```

and place it in the root of your project under any name, ex: ./custom_typings/audio.d.ts.

Here, I have just done it for an mp3 file.
After this go to your tsconfig.json and under "typeRoots" add the custom_typings folder.

```
"typeRoots": [
  "node_modules/@types",
  "custom_typings/"
]
```

Once this is done you can just import the audio file from anywhere and use it normally as you would.

```
import {audioFile} from '../../../../assets/audio/audioFile.mp3';

TrackPlayer.add({
id: '1',
url: audioFile,
title: 'Example title',
artist: 'Example Artist',
artwork: 'https://picsum.photos/100',
});
```

Comment: This didn't work for me, I had to use a variation of your and Yan's answer. I put `declare module '*.m4a';` in `/typings/audio.d.ts`, then had changed my `"include"` to `"include": ["src", "typings"]`. Changing `typeRoots` did nothing for me for some reason.

Answer (score 17):

Found a solution to the issue. Instead of using ES6 `import` use ES5 `require()` for audio files. It works and the [typescript](/questions/tagged/typescript) compiler doesn't complain.

`const alarm = require("./audio/alarm.mp3");`

Comment: The problem with this answer is that `@typescript-eslint/no-var-requires` throws lint errors on an ES5 import.  Sure, I can disable the rule but why would typescript not provide a ES6 method to import audio files?

Comment: Don't know. Ask them, and let us know.

Answer (score 1):

You can add typing to the mp3 files, if you are using typescript. To do this, create a types directory at the root directory with a defined file asset.d.ts and include in your configuration file:

types/asset.d.ts

```
declare module "*.mp3" {
  const value: any;
  export default value;
}
```

Then, add this to tsconfig.json:

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    //...
  },
  "include": [
    "src/*",
    "types/*"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Place it in the `assets` folder in order to access it. 
The following is on how to use it with images, however it works the same with audio files:

[How to load image (and other assets) in Angular an project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42793292/how-to-load-image-and-other-assets-in-angular-an-project)

Comment: I import the file, create a new Audio instance and call .play() and it plays, but I still get the compiler error... btw is assets/ supposed to be inside src/ ?

Comment: If you want it on compile time it should be inside the src folder. Everything outside of the src folder is not accesable for the compiler.

Comment: Still not working... Cannot find module './assets/audio/alarm.mp3'...

Comment: The typescript compiler is messed up, cause I have no issues when importing audio in a vanilla javascript react app. Thanks any way.