# How can I import an image into typescript? he says "cannot find module"

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm a beginner with typescript and want to know why I can't import an image from my assets folder. I have an image folder and vscode says that the module cannot be found.

This is the error I got:

```
ERROR in src/app/tool-box/tool-box/ao-bar/ao-bar.service.ts:3:19 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '../../../../assets/objects-ao-bar/fabio.png'.
import Fabio from '../../../../assets/objects-ao-bar/fabio.png';
Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
```

Comment: TypeScript import is not applicable to PNG (and any other assets). "import" is used to import TypeScript code from other *.ts files.

Comment: how can i import .png so?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to import an image in typescript. Most likely you are trying to add an image in your angular project refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42793292/how-to-load-image-and-other-assets-in-angular-an-project).

Comment: i want to save an image in a variable but when i import myImg from '../../assets/myimg.png' it doesn't find the image

Comment: Are you going to process images bitmap? How are you going to use loaded image object in your TypeScript?

Comment: well, i have an array in which i add objects and each object consists of id, name and img. then i will display the image. I have the image in my assets folder, I want to save the image in a variable so that I can access object.img

Comment: In this case each item in your array should hold "id" and "imageUri" (string field, which will store the path to your image). Later you can bind it like `<img [src]="item.imageUri">` in your HTML. In Angular there is no sense to load image assets as TypeScript objects.