# How to add an image using Angularjs

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I started developing a web application using Angularjs. I tried to add an image to the page. The image is not displayed on the page.

```
img src="src/assets/img/f1.png" alt="icon"
```

I used above mentioned tag and path inside <>.
Can anyone give step by step instructions to add an image using Angularjs?

Thank you!

Comment: `<img src="src/assets/img/f1.png" alt="icon">` - check your image path (right click "open-with"). In general your Q is too general - please read this article: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Related Q: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42793292/how-to-load-image-and-other-assets-in-angular-an-project. General broken image: https://blog.teamtreehouse.com/how-to-fix-a-broken-image

Comment: could you give your project tree to see the folders and files, tell which file has the `<img>` and were is the `f1.png`

Answer (score 0):

Try relative path from place you are.
./ means current directory
../ means higher directory
try
src="../assets/f1.png