# After upgrading to Angular 14, images are not loaded from assests folder. Am I missing any configuration, can anyone help me with a solution

Tags: html, angular, web, browser

[image]
[image]

Am I missing any configuration in Angular 14?

From `<img [src]="assets/images/sidebarNav">` tried using `./, ../`

This is not working for me.

I used
[How to load image (and other assets) in Angular an project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42793292/how-to-load-image-and-other-assets-in-angular-an-project)

Comment: I tried all those, the reason I found is that after upgrading from angular 8 to angular 14. I removed --deploy-url from ng serve. So my images are not loading. Can anyone help how to add deploy url or basehref in angular 14

Comment: `<img [src]="'assets/images/sidebarNav'">` See that the src is under single quotes

Answer (score 0):

Square brackets (`[]`) represent the *one-way* property binding from the component logic (data) to the view (target element).

If you write the source-path to the image in the view-page (html), you doesn't need property binding.

But you are mixing two things here. Either you remove the squared brackets `<img src="/assets/images/sidebarNav">` or you need [property binding](https://angular.io/guide/property-binding) like `<img [src]="itemImageUrl">` and set the variable `itemImageUrl = 'assets/images/sidebarNav';` in the component file.

But that didn't work on Angular 8 either, so this has nothing to do with your upgrading to version 14.